# how to save all images from a website in python

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

For my image processing practice, I want some of the images  from this site: https://511ny.org/cctv
and it seems that I have no access to their 'src' to use in BeautifulSoup and extract the images.
If you may have any solution for this issue please inform me.
here is my code which didn't get any response:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

response = urlopen('https://511ny.org/cctv')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
pics = soup.findAll('img')
for pic in pics:
    print('img src: ', pic['src'])
```

I followed up for another solution and that is downloading directly all the images from the website, but I couldn't find any tutorials to do it with python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I did this I create the Xpath for every image and then get the source code

```
import requests
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import urllib.request


PATH=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
driver= webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
page=driver.get(r'https://511ny.org/cctv')

try:
    main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="cctvTable"]/tbody'))
    ) # I used XPATH of the table
    print (main.text)
except:
    driver.quit()

items=main.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr') # I use tr tag

for item in items:
    # print(item.text)
    #Get id
    identificador=item.get_attribute('data-id') 
    
    #Creating xpath and getting the image
    xpath='//*[@id="{}img"]'.format(identificador) 
    imagen=item.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)[0]
    src=imagen.get_attribute('src')  
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(src,'{}.jpg'.format(identificador))
```

Thank you

Comment: Wow, Thanks, You saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Dear @Jaime, thanks again. I want to do the same in https://511.alaska.gov/cctv which has the exact structure, but it doesn't give me the images like the old one.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it doesn't have the exact structure. I am trying to figure it out.

Comment: If you need some help create a topic I would be glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

images in this website are not present in the initial html file but loaded dynamically through execution of javascript and beautifulsoup/urllib are not going to execute them for you.

to crawl dynamic websites you should use a sort of headless browser like [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) which has python library to communicate with it. these browsers are just like normal browsers but with one difference; they are controlled by your code instead of the user.

a better alternative to selenium would be puppeteer but i used it in node.js and i'm not sure of it's python binding quality.